# Как экранировать спецсимволы при создании каталога?

Tags: python

подскажите пожалуйста как экранировать спецсимволы при создании каталога.

```
import os
os.mkdir(str(name))
```

Comment: `r` перед строкой

Comment: Или `\` перед каждым спецсимволом

Comment: проблема в том, что name формируется динамически

Comment: Пройти по строке функцией replace()

Comment: ...что-то не получается в официальной документации найти список спесимволов

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Имя_файла

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такой кодек - string-escape.

```
name.encode('string-escape')
```